# How can I seperate a string into individual characters in c++?

Tags: c++

As the title says, how can I seperate a string into individual characters in c++? For example, if the string is "cat" how can I separate that into the characters c,a, and t?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do with the characters? They are already separate inside the string, you can access them at will.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `operator[]`. e.g.

```
std::string cat{"cat"};
if(cat[0] == 'c')
    //stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `std::string` you can simply use `.c_str( )` that will give you an array of the chars.

In `c++11` you could also do:

```
for( auto c : a )
{
    cout << c << '\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/UAyxTo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store them in a vector:

```
string str("cat");
vector<char> chars(str.begin(), str.end());

for (char c : chars)
    cout << c << endl;
```

Comment: You don't even need to make a vector. You can just say `for(char& c: str)`